# Automated encrypted backup to email

Tags: windows, email, encryption

I have some sensitive data (about 3 Megabytes) on a computer running Windows that I want to backup regularly to a different computer. The computer with the data on it will be used by someone else, the backup process should therefore be as simple as possible, a one-click solution would be nice.

My idea now is to just encrypt the files and send an email to a mail-account set up for that purpose.

How could I encrypt the files, with which program? And how can I send the encrypted files via mail automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Izarcc (Izarc command line) to compress and encrypt the backup files.
http://www.izarc.org/izarccl.html
You can use blat to send the compressed archive via email 
http://www.blat.net/
You can easily write a batch file to combine the compress/encrypt/send-by-email task.

Anyhow, I suggest you to use the more convenient solution offered by Crashplan.
http://b2.crashplan.com/landing/index.html
Install, configure and forget it.